# Capture by Reference - when does member-variable change?

Tags: c++, lambda

Trying to understand *how* and *when* a variable that is captured by reference changes in Lambdas.

I have the following example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

function<int(int)> func1( int y ) {
    return [&]( int argument ) {
        return argument + y;
    };
}

function<int(int)> func2( int y ) {
    class Lambda { public:
            Lambda( int& data ) : m_data( data ) {
                cout << "ctor: " << m_data << endl;
            }
            int operator () ( int argument ) {
                cout << "data lambda: " << m_data << endl; // why and when does m_data change?
                cout << "argument lambda: " << argument << endl;
                return m_data + argument;
            }
        const int& m_data;
    };

    return Lambda( y );
}

int main() {
    // rewritten lambda
    auto lambda1 = func1( 1 );
    auto result1 = lambda1( 10 );
    cout << "lambda2( 10 ) = "  << result1 << endl;

    // C++ lambda
    auto lambda2 = func2( 1 );
    auto result2 = lambda2( 10 );
    cout << "lambda2( 10 ) = "  << result2 << endl;
}
```

[Link to Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/6956nY15f)

The output is:

```
lambda2( 10 ) = 20
ctor: 1
data lambda: 10
argument lambda: 10
lambda2( 10 ) = 20
```

I tried to understand at what point the member `m_data` is changed from `1` to `10` and from where.

Comment: I could be wrong; I'm up for learning something today. :)  But to me it looks like there's no _capturing_ occurring here.  You pass a reference to `y` (the argument to the `func` function) to the Lambda class, but `y` falls out of scope.  This seems like UB to refer to `m_data` after `func` has returned.  In practice, `y` is likely a location on the stack and `m_data` holds the address of that stack location (but the function has exited), which seems like a fire hazard.

Comment: You have indeed dangling reference.

Comment: [And a useful tool called address sanitizer catches this error](https://godbolt.org/z/oxr1oK381)

Comment: @Wyck Thanks! So it is just coincidence that it changed the reference to 10 (due to UB)?
Is there a way to capture by (maybe const-) reference to not have it dangling?

Comment: Maybe your example is too minimal, but I don't understand your motivation for referring to `y` (in particular, it seems like you want to be able to modify `y` because you maintain a reference to `y` in `m_data`).  For example, how about if `m_data` were simply not a reference?  Would that be acceptable?  _Capturing_ is like an actual thing that happens with a real lambda, but you still wouldn't capture `y` (or any local variable) by reference in this or any other case.  So I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish with the reference to `y`.

Comment: @Wyck we were given the task to explain Lambdas in C++ where a similar example showed up. I tried for a too long time to understand why suddenly the variable 'y' changed from 1 to 10. I even tried compiler options like `-Wall -pedantic` to get a hint where I went wrong. Having a dangling reference and it changing to exactly 10 did not cross my mind. I have rewritten the lambda to check what is going on.
But when not knowing about dangling references or sanitizer that help out, the option was to ask a question on here.. thank you very much for your help, much apprecciated!

Comment: This is an _undefined behavior_ case; the lambda is (in both cases) referencing a variable (argument `y` to `func1` or `func2`) that no longer exists, because it got out of scope when the function exited. That’s a dangling reference.

Comment: Any "capture by reference" (const or non-const) requires you to keep the referenced object alive. Since `y` is a parameter, its lifetime ends when the function ends. No type of reference will prevent `y` from being destroyed. You should use a capture-by-value instead.

Answer (score 1):

I think that if you rewrite you code like this, you will better understand capture by reference:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

std::function<int(int)> func1( int& y ) {
    return [&]( int argument ) {
        return argument + y;
    };
}

int main() {
    int a = 1;
    auto lambda1 = func1( a );
    auto result1 = lambda1( 10 );
    std::cout << "lambda( 10 ) = "  << result1 << std::endl;
    a = 10;
    std::cout << "lambda( 10 ) = "  << lambda1(10) << std::endl;
}
```